# What isolation level do I need to make sure a cross-database INSERT...SELECT happens atomically?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, locking, atomic

I have a source table that drives the content of a second table. I have two or more processes that will be running for this (with different additions to the where clause). All essentially use the statement below. Somehow I am getting duplicates in the destination table. I am not currently specifying an isolation level - or any locking hints. The SQL Server is running 2005 which is something I cannot change (I know 2008's `MERGE` would probably be applicable).

```
INSERT INTO tableDst 
    (PK, ...)
SELECT src.PK, ...
FROM tableSrc src
LEFT JOIN tableDst dst ON src.PK = dst.PK
WHERE dst.PK IS NULL
```

The two tables are in different databases. Both databases are on the same instance on the same server, so cross-database statements such as this are possible.

What isolation level or locking hints do I need to make this work in an atomic fashion, so duplicates are prevented? Do I need to wrap it in a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tableDst 
    (PK, ...)
SELECT src.PK, ...
FROM tableSrc src WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
LEFT JOIN tableDst dst ON src.PK = dst.PK
WHERE dst.PK IS NULL
```

That is equivalent to `SERIALIZABLE`, it will block reads to the source table selected rows.

Without knowing your precise scenario and testing not sure if you might also need:

```
INSERT INTO tableDst 
    (PK, ...)
SELECT src.PK, ...
FROM tableSrc src WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
LEFT JOIN tableDst dst WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) ON src.PK = dst.PK
WHERE dst.PK IS NULL
```